# Comic from late 80s with self-aware mainframe

Tags: story-identification, computers

I remember back in the late 80s there was comic strip in an IT publication that featured a mainframe computer that shared its thoughts on the jobs it was running. One of my favorites was when the computer thought "groan! 8 hours of number crunching" and in the next frame there was a balloon from the user who said either "division by zero!" or "general protection fault!" and the computer thought "there, that should keep him busy for a while". I left the company that had this magazine subscription and didn't think about it for years but would love to read more of them now.

I realize this is terribly obscure but if any of you folks could recollect the name of the strip or the publication it was in, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.